# Datatable in twig, remove extra columns

Tags: javascript, mysql, datatable

I am using datatables to pull data and display a sort able with pagination table.

The data that is being pulled only has 5 columns.

Currently  Order #  column is blank so the data starts generating on the second column.

How can i push the data results to show on FIRST column rather than the second (Name).

Even with removing the extra  and leaving only 5 this then shows 4 columns and leaves the first TH blank.

**TABLE HTML FORMAT**

```
   <table id="table" width="100%">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th>Order #</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Currecy</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Amount Received</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**ON PAGE JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        var order = {
            settings: {
                ajaxUrl: ''
            },
            init: function() {
                order.initDataTable();
            },
            initDataTable: function() {

                var callBack = function() {
                };

                var dataList = $('#table').DataTable({
                    'responsive': true,
                    'processing': true,
                    'serverSide': true,
                    'ajax': {
                        "url" : order.settings.ajaxUrl,
                        "data" :function(d){
                        }
                    },
                    'columnDefs': [
                        { 'orderable': false, 'targets': [] },
                        { 'searchable': false, 'targets': [] }

                    ],
                    'order': [[0, 'desc']],
                    drawCallback: function() {
                        callBack();
                    },
                });

                $('.content-container').removeClass('has-loading');
                $('.content-container-content').removeClass('hide');
            },

        };

        order.settings.ajaxUrl = '{{ path('ajax_user_order_list') }}';
        order.init();
    });
</script>
```

**AJAX CONTROLLER **

```
   /**
     * @Route("/user_order_list", name="ajax_user_order_list")
     */
    public function user_order_listAction(Request $request, AuthService $authService)
    {

        $get = $request->query->all();

        $result = array(
            "draw" => intval($get['draw']),
            "recordsTotal" => 0,
            "recordsFiltered" => 0,
            "data" => array()
        );

        $authService =$authService;
        if(!$authService->isLoggedIn()) return $authService->redirectToLogin();
        $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('App:UserOrderTokenEntity')->userOrderList($get, $authService->getUser());

        foreach($data['results'] as $row) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('dashboard_order_details', array(
                    'id' => base64_encode($row['id'])
            ));

            $action = "<a class='action-button-style text-primary' href='$url'>".substr($row['address'],0,5) . (strlen($row['address']) > 7 ? '...' : '') ."</a>" ;

            $values = array(
                "<div class='tranx-status ". ($row['status']  == 'Completed' ? 'tranx-status-approved' : ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? 'tranx-status-pending' : 'tranx-status-cancled' )) ."'><em class='ti ". ($row['status']  == 'Completed' ? 'ti-check' : ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? 'ti-alert' : 'ti-close' )) ."'></em>",
                "<a class='orderList' href='javascript:void(0);' data-transaction='".$row['id']."'>".sprintf("%06d", $row['id'])."</a>" ,
                $row['network'],
                '+' . number_format($row['tokenAmt'], 0, '' , ','),
                '+' . number_format($row['amt'], 5, '.' , ','),
                "<a class='orderList' href='javascript:void(0);' data-transaction='".$row['id']."'>".substr($row['address'],0,5) . (strlen($row['address']) > 7 ? '...' : '') ."</a>",
                "<a class='orderList' href='javascript:void(0);' data-transaction='".$row['id']."'><em class='ti ti-more-alt'></em></a>" ,

            );

            $result['data'][] = $values;
        }

        $result['recordsTotal'] = $data['total'];
        $result['recordsFiltered'] = $data['total'];
        

        return new JsonResponse($result);
    }
```

I have tried to remove  so there is only 5 but this displays a blank 1st column and cut off my last column required.

I have also tried to define the columnDefs as follows.

```
 columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: 5,
        //defaultContent: ''
      }
```